# A function to get the length(time) of an audio file

Tags: vba

I have got this far but when I set the value for 'Folder' it is empty and the 'FolderPath' is "F:\Video Clips" what am I doing wrong

```
Function GetFileLength(FolderPath As String, FileName As String) As Date
'
' Get the run time of a audio/video file
'
' Set Up
Dim Shell As Object
Dim Folder As Object
Dim File As Object

Set Shell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set Folder = Shell.Namespace(FolderPath)
'Set Folder = Shell.Namespace("F:\Video Clips")
Set File = Folder.ParseName(FileName)

' Get time
  If LCase(Right(FileName, 3)) = "avi" Then
    GetFileLength = Folder.GetDetailsOf(File, 27)
  Else
    GetFileLength = ""
  End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with the data type `variant` for the folder path in your function. Also have a look at the documentation of [Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell-namespace).

```
Function GetFileLength(FolderPath As Variant, FileName As String) As Date
'
' Get the run time of a audio/video file
'
' Set Up
Dim Shell As Object
Dim Folder As Object
Dim File As Object

Set Shell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set Folder = Shell.Namespace(FolderPath)
'Set Folder = Shell.Namespace("F:\Video Clips")
Set File = Folder.ParseName(FileName)

' Get time
  If LCase(Right(FileName, 3)) = "avi" Then
    GetFileLength = Folder.GetDetailsOf(File, 27)
  Else
    GetFileLength = ""
  End If

End Function
```

PS Another bug you have is that the `else` condition `GetFileLength = ""` will fail  because a string is not a date. Maybe you should use `GetFileLength = CDate(0)` or whatever you think is appropriate.